# docker-compose tomcat - mapear diretório externo

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

Tenho uma aplicação rodando no tomcat aonde quando eu faço upload de uma imagem, ela salva em "portal/WEB-INF/classes/static/img" que é um diretório dentro da minha aplicação. O problema é que quando eu atualizo a aplicação, o tomcat destrói o diretório e recria e eu perco as imagens salvas. Gostaria de mapear um diretório fora da minha aplicação (ex.: /opt/img) para salvar essas imagens, isso é possível via docker-compose?

Services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:8.5-jre8
    volumes:
      - ./Tomcat/Webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
      - ./Tomcat/Logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs
      - ./Tomcat/Webapps/portal/WEB-INF/classes/static/img:/opt/img
      - ./tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
      - ./server.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é preciso necessáriamente salvar fora do container docker, isso acontece pois você não possui um volume para sua aplicação, tente realizar a montagem de um volume seguindo a documentação https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ que dará tudo certo, o docker é como uma maquina virtual, toda vez que reiniciado limpa seus "caches" para não consumir volume do seu disco, porém se você sentir necessidade( que é o seu caso) você aloca um volume para o seu container docker, onde o volume ocupa uma pequena parte do seu disco